# Constructor got deleted by compiler when I have a virtual method?

Tags: c++

I came across a situation that can be summarized in the following code snippet. Basically, I would like my classes to inherit constructors. It works, but compilation fails as soon as I have a virtual method defined in `C`. Apparently the compiler deleted the constructor.

My questions are:

1. Why does the compiler do that?
2. I can work around by defining constructors in B and C and delegate eventually to A's constructor. Is there a better way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A() = delete;
  A(int x) : x_(x) {}
  int x_;
};

struct B : public A {
};

struct C : public B {
  // What? defining virtual method kills the inherited constructor
  //virtual void foo() {}
};

int main() {
  C c{10};
  std::cout << "Hello World: " << c.x_ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's kind of cool. You can't inherit constructors, so I wonder if that's a bug or some fun little edge... Is this like of Aggregate initialization disabled by the `virtual` function. I must do some reading. A moment, assuming someone who already knows this trick doesn't come along.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like I was A) right and B) too slow.

Comment: Key point: The constructor did not get `delete`d; It didn't exist in the first place. [Documentation for Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Comment: According to my experiments, your code fails to compile in C++17, even without the virtual function. It only compiles in C++20. Perhaps you should make that clear (or add the c++20 tag).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Constructors are inherited only when you explicitly declare the inherited constructors. This is done as follows:

```
struct B : public A {
    using A::A;
};

struct C : public B {
    using B::B;
};
```

In your program, you are not using inherited constructors; you are using aggregate initialization. Adding a virtual function makes `C` no longer an aggregate, so aggregate initialization cannot be used. If you declare inherited constructors, then you can construct `C` without having to use aggregate initialization.

Comment: Since C++17, aggregates can't have inherited constructors.  I wonder, though - is `C` really an aggregate at all, when `A` is not an aggregate?  `A` has a user-declared constructor, so `A` is not an aggregate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Being an aggregate isn't a transitive property like trivial copyability and standard layout. Roughly speaking an aggregate is a type that equals the sum of its parts (base classes + non-static members) without imposing any additional constraints on the values of those parts or access thereto